# SQL Server Linked Server query taking hours to complete

Tags: sql-server

One of the SQL select query taking 10 minutes to pull 2 million records in local SQL server.
When i run same query in other SQL DB server using linked server it takes hours to complete. The servers are in different locations(different US states) and different domains, This is just plain select query and it doesn't contains any joins, this issue observed for all the tables not just for single table.
what might be the reason for this issue and how would i fix it.

I gone through this below similar post but seems my case is different,

[Executing query against Azure SQL db using Linked server takes hours](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168537/executing-query-against-azure-sql-db-using-linked-server-takes-hours)

Below is the LocalQuery Estimated Execution Plan

[image]

Below is the Remote Query Estimated Execution Plan

[image]

Comment: Have you look at the execution plan ? I'm guessing that when you run it locally, it does an index seek (your table should be pretty big).

Comment: 10 minutes for 2 million rows locally makes me think your tables are pretty wide and / or each row is pretty heavy. How many columns are you selecting? As Dominique mentioned, your **execution plan** should point you in the right direction, and would be helpful for us to help you if you could post it here. I would bet it has a **Remote Scan** operator going on which is testing your network's limitations.

Comment: Thanks J.D and Dominique for your reply.  Its happening for all the tables, the table i am querying had 162 columns. I am selecting all the columns, the local query estimated execution plan has 'Clustered Index Scan' and remote query had 'Remote Query' 100 cost.

Comment: If it were me I'd write the data out to a file with BCP remotely, use the best compression software (winRAR ?) and compress the file and split over multiple files. Then use Robocopy to transfer the data locally & BCP or BULK INSERT to load it to the local SQL. More steps but I bet you can knock a few hours off the completion time.